# Приватные комнаты для чата на Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Есть необходимость сделать чат с приватными комнатами, используя [Socket.io](https://socket.io/). Но, ведь, при использовании:

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event');
```

любой, кто подпишется на событие при помощи `socket.onAny(listener)` сможет читать сообщения, или я не прав? Какой подход тут избрать?